# The effect affects all the button in css

Tags: html, css

Im wondering why is this happening. If I hover a button, all buttons applies the effect which supposedly not. I want to apply the effect only on the button that I've hover.

```css
.buttons{
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.buttons:after{
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.buttons:hover:after{
 width: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Did you try to add effect directly to hovered button tag(not for :after element)?

Comment: yes...............

Comment: You could put the `transition: all 0.3s ease-out` rule on the `.buttons::after` selector (not on the `:hover`), and remove `transition: none`. This property sets the transition effect, so the animation will still still only happen on hover. I don't think that will solve your problem, but it will reduce your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `width: 120%;` in `:hover` is measuring relative to the document (which is the pseudo-element's offsetParent), not the button.

Add `position: relative;` to the button to make that the offset parent instead:

```css
.buttons{
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.buttons:after{
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.buttons:hover:after{
 width: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed the below property,

Update css :

```
.buttons{
  position:relative;/* Add this property */
}
```

```css
.buttons{
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position:relative;
}


.buttons:after{
 content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.buttons:hover:after{
 width: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="buttons">Submit</a>
```